# How to save json as vertex properties values using gremlin query

Tags: javascript, java, c#, gremlin, gremlin-server

I am trying to save a json as a vertex's property value. Below is my query.

```
String createVrtx = "g.addV('Person').property('id','123').property('Address','{"City":"bang","pin": "123456"}')";
```

but getting Runtime Excution Exception query can't compile.

So what i to do for submit json as vertex value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely need to escape your double quotes in the json String.
`String createVrtx = "g.addV('Person').property('id','123').property('Address','{\"City\":\"bang\",\"pin\": \"123456\"}')";`